# Use Model Multiple Times In Different Model MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a model made who has uses a Child Model 2x as one of it's properties.  I can get all of that data loaded correctly into the model but I can't figure out how to Display it into a datagrid Properly.  Using test rows I know it's binding, but I can't get it to display any properties.

Model

```
class BidLine
    {
        public TestProduct CompetitorItem;
        public TestProduct BEItem;


        public ObservableCollection<BidLine> LoadProduct()
        {

            var tList = new ObservableCollection<BidLine>();

            tList.Add(new Model.BidLine
            {
                BEItem = new TestProduct
                {
                    ProductID = "test1",
                    VendorID = "vnd1"
                },

                CompetitorItem = new TestProduct
                {
                    ProductID = "test2",
                    VendorID = "vnd2"
                }
            });

            tList.Add(new Model.BidLine
            {
                BEItem = new TestProduct
                {
                    ProductID = "test1",
                    VendorID = "vnd1"
                },

                CompetitorItem = new TestProduct
                {
                    ProductID = "test2",
                    VendorID = "vnd2"
                }
            });

            return tList;
        }

    }
```

Child Model

```
class TestProduct : ModelBase
{
    private string _productid;
    public string ProductID
    {
        get { return _productid; }
        set
        {
            _productid = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ProductID");
        }
    }

    private string _vendorID;
    public string VendorID
    {
        get { return _vendorID; }
        set
        {
            _vendorID = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("VendorID");
        }
    }
}
```

View Model

```
class ProductViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<BidLine> Products { get; set; }

    public ProductViewModel()
    {
        var dl = new BidLine();
        Products = dl.LoadProduct();
    }
```

Edit:

XAML Code

```
  <Grid>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=BEItem.ProductID}" Header="ProductID"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: You need to show us the XAML for the datagrid.

Comment: Please add the XAML as @AQuirky suggested so that a complete picture of what is causing the problem can be seen.

Comment: Added Edit with XAML Code

Comment: You cannot bind to fields and it will not work. Change these `public TestProduct CompetitorItem; public TestProduct BEItem` to properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding does not work with fields.  You need to have properties.  So convert BEItem and CompetitorItem into properties...

```
    public TestProduct CompetitorItem { get; set; }
    public TestProduct BEItem { get; set; }
```

Things will start working.  The best way to debug the binding is to watch the output window.  If you had looked at the output window you would have seen this...

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'BEItem' property not found on 'object' ''BidLine' (HashCode=31093287)'
```

This clearly indicates that the binding engine is looking for a property BEItem when all that is present is a BEItem field.

Comment: It worked!  Thank you for the help.  I checked the output window before I made the changes you suggested and didn't see the error you showed below, not sure why it didn't show for me.